# In python why does Hash not check equality for objects with same hash and identity?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python resolves hash collisions by checking for equality if there is a collision. Why does 'a in s' not check for equality but 'b in s' does? Is there a call to id() between **hash**() and **eq**()?

```
In [107]: class Foo(object):
 ...:      def __eq__(self, other):
 ...:          print "equality"
 ...:          return False
 ...:      def __ne__(self, other):
 ...:          print "not equality"
 ...:          return not self == other
 ...:      def __hash__(self):
 ...:          print "hash"
 ...:          return 7
 ...: a = Foo()
 ...: b = Foo()
 ...: s = set()
 ...:

In [108]: s.add(a)
hash

In [109]: a in s
hash
Out[109]: True

In [110]: b in s
hash
equality
Out[110]: False
```

Comment: In cpython, the "is" check is done in `Objects/setobject.c::set_lookkey` with the C statement `if (startkey == key) return entry;`.

Comment: Thanks for the python reference! That implementation was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Python containers assume that all elements are equal to themselves. The equality comparison routine they use does an `is` check before attempting the more expensive `==`. Since `a is a`, the `==` check is skipped.