# "typed" parameter for Python's functools.lru_cache not working as described

Tags: python, functools

My initial experience using the `typed` parameter for Python's `functools.lru_cache` decorator has given me results that don't seem to match its description. **It seems very unlikely this is a bug, so I expect I'm doing something wrong**

To quote Python's documentation (available from the `help` built-in) regarding the behavior of `typed`:

> If *typed* is True, arguments of different types will be cached separately.
> For example, f(3.0) and f(3) will be treated as distinct calls with
> distinct results.

My example below (tested with Python 3.10.4) uses *what I think* is a similar case to what is described in the documentation quoted above, and yet my results indicate that the type of the function argument **does** matter - even when `typed` is set to `False`.

```
>>> import functools
>>> @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128, typed=False)
... def f(v):
...     print("Called 'f'")
...     return v + 1
... 
>>> f(4)
Called 'f'
5
>>> f(4.)
Called 'f'
5.0
>>> f.cache_info()
CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=2, maxsize=128, currsize=2)
>>> # No hits - this would seem to contradict the documentation
>>> # Repeating the same exact calls as before, DOES produce hits
>>> f(4)
5
>>> f(4.)
5.0
>>> f.cache_info()
CacheInfo(hits=2, misses=2, maxsize=128, currsize=2)
```

While there are many references to `functools.lru_cache` on the web - I can't find any that *actually include* a code sample where the behavior of `typed` is significant.  Thus, I am at a loss.

Comment: The last part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69780424/13843268) may be of some help regarding caching single arguments of certain types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You looked at the `help` output, which unfortunately isn't complete here. The [online docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) say

> (Some types such as str and int may be cached separately even when typed is false.)

This is due to an [internal optimization](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.7/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c#L819) in how `lru_cache` computes hash keys - if the function is called with a single argument of type exactly `int` or `str`, and `typed` is False, the argument will be used as a cache key directly, instead of being wrapped in a tuple.

Note that the docs do not promise exactly what types will be cached separately, or in what situations they will be cached separately. The docs only say some types *may* be cached separately, and give `int` and `str` as examples.

Comment: So - to make sure I understand - the 'help' documentation itself has a bug because their example with a float and int argument would never be memoized with the decorator?

Comment: @aloysius72: The `help` output is missing information, and uses a really bad example.

Comment: Ahh, so the example cited in the 'help' documentation results in different cache keys of (3.0,) and 3.